# Password.text how to compare with stored password in sqlite3

Tags: objective-c, iphone, sqlite, uitextfield

How can I compare a password.text to text password stored in the database

Answer (score 0):

Get data from database using SELECT query and compare both passwords

Comment: @reena... Ya I know that.. I wanted to know how to do such a query in objective c .

Comment: @reena .. are you reena from Rehna Hain Tere Dil Main ..hehehe :)